# How can I mitigate humming from a streetside electrical transformer?

Tags: electrical, noise-reduction

I have humming coming in and I think it is from the green box on ground, electrical transformer, in the front yard. It also has a hum. I have reported to electric company, but I don't think they will do anything.

House built 2003. Florida. Land O Lakes Area. Neighborhood has underground electrical utilities. Green Transformer Box in the yard. Hum coming from box--can hear low noise constantly making noise. House--can almost not hear when walking around. Once sitting on furniture or laying on bed can be heard constantly. Would not have bought the house if I had hear it now stuck. Wanting to do something to make the noise go away.

Whole house hums. What steps can I take in the house or on the side of the house to stop the humming from coming into the house.

Anyone has suggestions and has been able to get results.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Wonder if there's a humbucking device for room space. If you are into audio, try generating a sound at 120 Hz but off-phase and playing that in your room. See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_hum

Answer (score 4):

That noise can really get annoying.

Hate to say it, but I'm not sure there is much you can do about it in your house. However, there are steps the utility company can take to mitigate it.

Here is a writeup of what you are dealing with:
https://electrical-engineering-portal.com/transformer-irritating-hum

They may have to adjust how it is mounted, or worst case (for them) change the transformer as some are noisier than others. You will probably have to be persistent.

Comment: The fact that it is felt/heard more when on furniture means the hum is traveling through the ground.  You can't really do anything to isolate your whole home from the hum, so, I guess unfortunately, the electric company will have to fix something.

Comment: Good luck with that! I don't see any power company spending thousands af dollars to replace a working transformer, noisy but normal.

Comment: @Gunner I didn't say it would be easy... Might have to be the proverbial squeaky wheel. If the power company is a dead end, see if you have a local civic association. They usually have contacts that can navigate some of these issues.

Answer (score 1):

White noise.  Try running a fan at night in your bedroom - it might be less irritating than the transformer buzz.